# How to divide business logic in one react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i use react.js to build my spa app.
I use functional style to make my components.
As the business logic gonna bigger, there are inevitably many functions.
So i tried to divide in to multiple components. Because it's hard to put many codes in one file even if it is just a 1 component.

However, this also has obvious limitations. In the case of complex components, there are a large number of event callback functions in addition to the functions directly called by the user.
Depending on the size of the component, it is sometimes difficult to write all the logic in one jsx file, so I want to divide the code into different files as needed. (Like c# partial class)

However, this is not easy. As an example, let's assume that the callback functions are made external functions of other files and imported into this component jsx file and used. But it seems that the component states, props information and the dispatch function also should be passed as parameters to the function. This seems hassle but except this, i have no idea a way to access this component's states, props, dispatch function from a function in another file.)

```
//For example of callback function
const onHoldButtonClicked = (state, props, dispatch, event) =>
{
    ~~~
}
//For example of normal function
const updateValidUser = (state, props, dispatch, userInfo, data) =>
{
    let id = userInfo.id;
    if(id == data.passID)
    {
         if(props.valid == 10)
            dispatch({action: 'ChangeUser', user: id});
    }
}
```

In React, how to divide logic(functions) when the logic gonna bigger in one component? (In general case)
Even if it is divided into several components, a big component inevitably has many functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend to extract logic into hooks and place these hooks into their own files.

hook.js

```js
const useAwesomeHook = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("default");

  const myCoolFunction = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('do smth cool', someState);
  }, [someState]);

  return myCoolFunction;
};

export default useAwesomeHook;
```

main.js

```js
import useAwesomeHook from './hook';

const Main = ({ someProperty }) => {
  const myCoolFunction = useAwesomeHook(someProperty);

  return <button onClick={myCoolFunction}>Click me</button>;
};
```

Comment: Hmm your awesome hook seems just retrieve props from component. So if i want to use state and dispatch function in business logic function, then i must pass these  too as a 'useAwesomeHook''s parameter. Is it right?

Comment: No. You can use state inside of your hook. Hooks are allowed to use `useState` for example.

Comment: @HelloWorld I updated my answer with an example for state

Comment: Thanks for answering. Then how to share the states in each custom business logic hooks? For example like one custom hook gonna change multiple states and some are in another custom hooks.  Additionally I use useReducer. And in my case, there are common to change multiple states. If there are multiple states that need to be changed at the same time, is it better to put them together in one hooks? Or is it better to put state and dispatch function in a component and pass it to each multiple hooks?

Comment: If possible, I want to seperate the business logic into multiple hooks and share the states. To do this, it seems that you have to pass state or props as parameters of hooks, but I don't know whether this is a good design or a bad design. I need some senior's advice like you.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to pass state or setState functions to hooks. You should not have duplicate states in hooks, rather have the state in the parent component and pass functions to hooks to manipulate that state. Of course you can try and extract the state into smaller logical chunks and return the states from the hooks to use in the parent or in a different hook, but be careful that can create strange situations where a state is returned by a hook, but needed by another hook that refers its state to the next hook, kind of like a circle, so best practice to keep state in parent

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example for logic and business and component separation.
The separation makes your code testable, atomic, maintainable, readable and SRP(single responsibility rule )

```
 // Presentational component
    const QuantitySelector = () => {
      const { onClickPlus, onClickMinus, state } = useQuantitySelector();
      const { message, value } = state;
      return (
        <div className="quantity-selector">
          <button onClick={onClickMinus} className="button">
            -
          </button>
          <div className="number">{value}</div>
          <button onClick={onClickPlus} className="button">
            +
          </button>
          <div className="message">{message}</div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default QuantitySelector;
```

and below code is the above component logic

```
import { useState } from "react";

// Business logic. Pure, testable, atomic functions
const increase = (prevValue, max) => {
  return {
    value: prevValue < max ? prevValue + 1 : prevValue,
    message: prevValue < max ? "" : "Max!"
  };
};

const decrease = (prevValue, min) => {
  return {
    value: prevValue > min ? prevValue - 1 : prevValue,
    message: prevValue > min ? "" : "Min!"
  };
};

// Implementation/framework logic. Encapsulating state and effects here
const useQuantitySelector = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    value: 0,
    message: ""
  });
  const onClickPlus = () => {
    setState(increase(state.value, 10));
  };
  const onClickMinus = () => {
    setState(decrease(state.value, 0));
  };
  return { onClickPlus, onClickMinus, state };
};

export default useQuantitySelector;
```

Comment: Thanks & upvoted as the pattern seeks to separate business logic and makes it testable. However would you agree that the model (which is usually encapsulated in domain logic) is inside the react component still? Can the model - {value: <number>, message: <string>} be taken outside somehow? (or is it a react limitation)

Answer (score 2):

I separate components into the logic and UI by function composition.The idea came from [recompse](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) which I used before hooks came into react.
you can add two helper functions.
first one is `compose` you can learn more about it [here](https://www.codementor.io/@michelre/use-function-composition-in-javascript-gkmxos5mj):

```
    const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((y, f) => f(y), x);
    export default compose;
```

the second one is  `withHooks`:

```
    import React from 'react';
    export default (hooks) =>
    (WrappedComponent) =>
    (props) => {
        const hookProps = hooks(props);

        return (
            <WrappedComponent
                {...props}
                {...hookProps}
            />
        );
    }
```

with these two functions, you can put your logic in the `hooks` file  and pass the as props to your UI with `compose` file you can see sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-ltdzp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: why not use hooks since they are available and a thing in react?

Comment: @JulianKleine you can also use hooks. this example is mostly to separate logic from UI in case the component has complex logic.it's really your decision to use or not.

Comment: @JulianKleine I read your answer again and I think I'll use It

Comment: Cool, happy to collaborate

Answer (score 1):

what I usually do is create a folder for the big component, in the folder I create a functions file and put functions with state passed and other params necessary . as simple as that .

```
export const increment=(count,setCount)=>{...}
.
.
```

and in your component

```
import{increment,....} from './functions'
const Component=(props)=>{
  const [count,setCount]=useState(1)
  return <div>
    <button onClick={e=>increment(count,setCount)}> count ={count}</button>
</div>
}
```

Comment: You should use hooks if you pass state

Comment: Im doing this now, but not sure if its the best practice, Im kind of confuse to which approach Im goona follow, this one which is much simpler for me, or make custom Hooks which I haven't use since Im still new to react.

Comment: @Joe honestly you should get into custom hooks asap , but also you should explore other patterns you can do this by creating multiple projects , these projects don't have to be complicated just medium and simple stuff .